# Using this keyword inside es6 template string and passing that string to dangerouslySetInnerHtml

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contenteditable

```
`<span>
        <span contentEditable="false">
          <select
              selected=${currentPlaceholder.selected.value}
              onchange ={this.handleDropDown(${index})}
              class="custom-dropdown"
          >
                ${optionsList}
          </select>
        </span>
      </span>`
```

I want to pass class function to onchange attribute but this template string is returned to `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` . And therefore it says `this.handleDropDown is not a function` . 
I am not sure how to pass it properly

[image]

Comment: `this.handelDropDown is not a function` Spelling matters

Comment: @CertainPerformance changed it

Comment: @YashSharma have you bind the this.handleDropDown() in the constructor? and in react onchange is written like this onChange

Comment: @SubhanshuPandey - i am using fat arrow operator

Comment: @SubhanshuPandey - but it is passed to angerouslySetInnerHtml and hence can't use onChange

Comment: @YashSharma yes you are correct. You will need to write handleDropdown function  in componentdidmount then. yes it will work that way and call the function the select tag without this

Comment: @SubhanshuPandey you mean function inside a functon ?

Comment: but inside onchange i have to use this keyword as well

Comment: no like this, componentDidMount(){   function handleDropdown(index) {
    ........
}}, not necessary if you are passing it in dangeroushtml

Comment: but then i will loose out on the 'this' scope inside handleDropDown function

Comment: yes you will lose this scope.dangerouslySetInnerHTML is same as .innerHTML in javascript. It will inject the HTML string in the DOM node. Is dangerouslySetInnerHTML required in your code. ??

Comment: any other way then ? without loosing the scope ?

Comment: is dangerouslySetInnerHTML required in your code. I think  you can use it without it also. depends upon the situation i think

Comment: yes i think so because i want to render <br> tags . i am getting a template string from backend . and i have to render it and do manipulations on top of it .

Comment: @YashSharma  instead of this onchange ={this.handleDropDown(${index})} use this and check onchange =${this.handleDropDown(index)}